# How to do Unit Test when #if - #else statement

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing

I have a function as below to do Unit Test. As you can see, it contains macro #if DEBUG, the opposite is RELEASE, which is predefined macro by developer and associated with Solution/Project Configuration.

```
public static void Exception(String tag, Exception ex)
{
    Error(tag, $@"Exception: {ex.HResult.ToString("X")} Message: {ex.Message}");
#if DEBUG
    Error(tag, $@"StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
#endif
}
```

My question is how to write the corresponding Unit Test code? Mine is as below. But the coverage rate is not changed, which means my test case doesn't cover both DEBUG and RELEASE cases.

```
[Fact]
public void ExceptionTest()
{
    try
    {
        double num = 1 / 0.0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        Logger.Exception("UnitTest: Debug", e);
#else
        Logger.Exception("UnitTest: Release", e);
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#if DEBUG` is not a predefined makro by a developer but a [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) (a feature of C#).

You could write 2 tests and wrap the first one into a `#if DEBUG` while you wrap the other into a `#if RELEASE` block. Depending on your build configuration (and the set symbols) the appropriate test will be compiled while the other one is going to be ignored.

But to be honest, I can't really understand what you are trying to test there. Where is your assertion?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As you can see, the function is to print log (to file). I don't known how to use assertion to test it. Any idea?

Comment: The purpose of unit testing is to make sure that a piece of code does what it is supposed to to. I don't really know what functionality you want to test in your `Exception` method (which btw is quite a horrible name for a method because first it doesn't tell the interested reader nothing about what the method does and secondly collides with the type `Exception`). It seems that the only thing `Exception` does is calling the `Error` function with different parameters. So what is it exactly do you want to test?

Comment: The function Exception() is to print exception message/trace log to a file when an exception is catched. It will be invoked in the try...catch...  the catch part .